# IndexOutOfRangeException at the time of Login in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Asp.Net application at the time of Login, I am first authenticating the User then getting some important information in session variables and it's working fine too.
However after sometime when session expires and I have to login again then it shows `IndexOutOfRangeException` in `GetDetail()` method. Here is my Login Button Code:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
    string DefaultYear = GetDefaultFinYear();
    if (DefaultYear != string.Empty)
    {
        DefaultYear = "connect" + DefaultYear;
        Connections.Init(DefaultYear);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("CheckLogin_sp", Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()]);
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("option", "Authenticate".Trim());
            adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].Open();
            }
            SqlDataReader dr = adp.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                Session["value"] = "admin";
                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
                GetDetails();
                Response.Redirect("~/Masters/home.aspx", false);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
                txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].Close();
            adp.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].Close();
            adp.Dispose();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName");
    }        
}
```

`GetDetails()` Method:

```
private void GetDetails()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    cmd.Connection = Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()];
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "CheckLogin_sp";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("option", "GetDetails".Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pwd", txtPassword.Text);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Session["Name"] = dr["name"].ToString();
        Session["CompanyName"] = dr["CompanyName"].ToString();
        Session["UserId"] = dr["Id"].ToString();
        Session["Center"] = dr["Center"].ToString();
        Session["ClientCode"] = dr["ClientCode"].ToString();
        Session["UserImage"] = dr["Image"].ToString();
        Session["CurrentDatabase"] = dr["CurrentDatabase"].ToString();
        Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
        Connections.BillReport = dr["BillReport"].ToString();
        Connections.DuesReport = dr["DuesReport"].ToString();            
        Connections.GeneralReport = dr["GeneralReport"].ToString();
        Connections.PendingReport = dr["PendingReport"].ToString();
        Connections.RadiologyReport = dr["RadiologyReport"].ToString();
        Connections.HistoReport = dr["HistoReport"].ToString();
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Dispose();
    dr.Close();
}
```

Note:- When I check temporary files in my computer I found 6 GB temporary files in just 15 days. Is it because of heavy load of temporary files ? or something wrong in my Code ?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try to improve your code, this code is not good, in while loop you are assigning the session variable

Comment: Can you suggest, what should be the better code ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi can you show me your session expires code and where you are redirecting to login page?

Comment: In my master page I used this code at the time of page load if(Session["value"] == null) { response.redirect("default.aspx")} So whenever session expires it redirect to default.aspx

Comment: @Webruster Should I use dr.dispose() at the end of GetDetails() method ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi My question is where are you doing that value to null?. and another mistake i noted is , you shouldnt add username to session without getting successfull autentication of that username from the DB,

Answer (score 0):

**IndexOutOfRange exception** is thrown when you attempt to access (Read/ Write) an element of an array with an index which is outside the bounds of the array

As per your problem, I guess you are trying to read or write some array elements which are outside of your array boundary.

**for example:**
It's error related when you are retriving index record which is not exist.

See if there's 5 elements in array, But when you are trying to retrieve record at index 6 then it will generate Exception of kind **IndexOutOfRangeException**.

See here [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) for more details.

You can try this code:

```
 while (dr.Read() != null){
        // code goes here.
     } 

     OR 

 while(dr.Read() != ''){
        // code goes here.
     }
```

> If not solved, you must be debug your program.

Comment: Should I use dr.Dispose(); at the end of GetDetails() method ?

Comment: You can user dr.close(); instead of dr.Dispose(); because both method working same operation but close() method set timeout shortly. so, i woluld like to suggession to use close()l method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (dr.Read() != null)
```

Comment: can you explain please ?